# Java: How to load a file from within the current jar

Tags: java, file, jar, resources

I need to load a few sound files and an image from a resources package that is in the same directory as my main package. Is there a specific way to do this? Because I have tried to `class.getResource(filename)` but that gives a null pointer exception only when I'm running the actual jar file, and not in Eclipse.
Here's the error I get when I run this as a jar file:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources/randomDoorOpen.wav (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFloatFileReader.getAudioInputStream(WaveFloatFileReader.java:164)
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1179)
at com.andrewlalisofficial.ChatClientCore.playSound(ChatClientCore.java:184)
at com.andrewlalisofficial.ChatClientWindow$4.mouseClicked(ChatClientWindow.java:207)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6519)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3312)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4501)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: You can print the path `class.getResource("")` for debug.

Comment: You can use `getClass.getResource("relative/path/to/resource");` where the path is relative to the current class's package or `getClass.getResource("/absolute/path/to/resource");` where the path is absolute from the top of the default package

Comment: I understand that, it's just that using that same syntax for when I've exported the jar file doesn't work. It then returns a null pointer exception, as if it can no longer find the files.

Comment: @AndrewLalis Unzip the jar file and make sure that the resource has actually been included then

Comment: I have checked that the files do actually exist.

Comment: Your statement is ambiguous -- he didn't suggest that you check that the *files* exist, he suggested that you unzip the *jar file* and ensure that the resource exists in there.  Depending on how you are making the jar file, it would be easy to create a jar that didn't include the resource file.  Post a screenshot of a zip dump of the jar file.

Comment: The stack trace mentions a FileInputStream which of course is never going to work if the file is embedded in the jar as a resource. It's not a regular file and can't be accessed by FileInputStream. Are you sure that you are using getClass.getResource() as per the other's comments and not a File or FileInputStream ?

Comment: Perhaps include the code which makes the getClass.getResource() call